# Change the transmission range for the ns2 node

Tags: range, ns2, transmission

I am new in the ns2 and I want to change the transmission range for the node.

My space work 1000,1000. So, I hope if there is someone can help me by code or the way to change the node transmission range.

Comment: Google https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+node+transmission+range ... Example links : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSEplREllWEpJNDA/view?usp=sharing ... All ~2500 simulation examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your answer....I will check this links...My Best Regard